# Splitting a string in SQL using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to take a postal code looking like:

```
S7Y 6H5
```

that's in a table and display it as

```
S7Y & 6H5
```

I can't find a command that splits the string in sql.

Comment: Why do you have to do this in SQL? Can't you just do it once you've retrieved the information? Not saying your approach is wrong, but just wondering if this is really necessary.

Comment: Is it only ever a single space, and you you need the literal `'S7Y & 6H5'`, or do you want them in 2 seperate fields/columns?

Comment: Is [substring_index()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) what you are looking for?

Comment: also you should be able to use SUBSTR along with concatenation to make all kinds of variants.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL doesn't include a split function, but it does include a replace. You could use:

```
SELECT REPLACE('S7Y 6HS', ' ', ' & ')
```

The greater question for me, though, is why don't you do that in your application code?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Select REPLACE ('S7Y 6H5', ' ', ' & ')
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `INSERT`  `INSERT(str,pos,len,newstr)`

```
     SELECT INSERT('S7Y 6H5', 4, 0, ' & ');
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_insert